# Devise routing rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i am new to rails so any help will be much appreciated. I have successfully installed the gem devise. I have two table in my schema; Userrs (recruiters) & Userj (jobseekers).

> Question: i want to write a method that states if registered user is Userrs (recruiters) go to recruiters_path else if user is Userj (jobseekers) go to jobseekers_path. Any help or advise will be much appreciated.

application controller

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if is_userr?(current_userr)
      recruiters_path
    else
      jobseekers_path
    end
  end
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller write:

`if userr_signed_in?`

`redirect_to recruiters_path`

`else`

`redirect_to jobseekers_path`

`end`

Comment: thanks you @uday. since i used devise i do not have a controller for my users {recruiters & jobseekers) but i wrote the below coding in the application controller using your format and it works perfect fine:

 ***def after_sign_in_path_for(resources)
    if userr_signed_in?
      recruiters_path
    else
      jobseekers_path
    end
  end***